# read file line by line and continue later bash

Tags: bash, while-loop

I'm reading a text file line by line, but sometimes the process fail. In that case, while i'm trying to debug why it happens, I would like to restart the process, but from the last line that was processed. Is it possible? It is not hard to store what line it was, but I have no idea hoe to start the process, in an eficiente way (a brute force way is just to read all the file again, and check when we arrive to the line I want), in another run of the script.

I'm reading like this:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    do thing with $line
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Just use a file to save the state it was, last time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to store the breaking number line somewhere, then you can read or pass it directly to the script and use tail to skip the previous stuff:

```
from_line=${2:-0}
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    do thing with "$line"
done <  <(tail -n +"$from_line" "$1")
```

Comment: *No*,  if you pass a second arg to the script that will be the line number, if not the starting line will be zero

Comment: Even faster is if you track a byte offset rather than a line offset -- `tail` needs to read from the beginning (though it does so much faster than the shell's `read` builtin), whereas if you know the byte, it or `dd` can `seek()` directly to the right place.